# How do I to get multiple key with array_search()?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get matches routes from $routes array. if there are multiple array which have same "ur" value. I want to get all of them.

ordinary array item looks like;

```
[
   "controller" => "RegisterController",
   "method" => "GET",
   "url" => "/register",
   "action" => "index"
]
```

I'm getting item with my get_in_array method;

```
$routes = unserialize(apcu_fetch("routes"));
$route = get_in_array($this->url, $routes, "url");
```

helper

```
function get_in_array(string $needle,array $haystack,string $column){
    $key = array_search($needle, array_column($haystack, $column));
    // even if there are more than one same url, array search returns first one
    if (!is_bool($key)){
        return $haystack[$key];
    }
}
```

But `array_search()` method returns just first match. if there are two array with the same url (like `"/register"`) I can't get both of them. how do I get more than one matched result?

Comment: In this case maybe you could use a plain ol' `foreach` loop, and put matches into an array, and be happy.

Comment: but if there are many routes, it might be reduce performance of application ?

Comment: I don't know, but `array_column` has to create a brand new array each time, which is also time-consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boring solution using a `foreach` loop:

```
function get_in_array( string $needle, array $haystack, string $column){
    $matches = [];
    foreach( $haystack as $item )  if( $item[ $column ] === $needle )  $matches[] = $item;
    return $matches;
}
```

Using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
function get_in_array( string $needle, array $haystack, string $column ){
    return array_filter( $haystack, function( $item )use( $needle, $column ){
      return $item[ $column ] === $needle;
    });
}
```

Comment: `$matches[] = $item` I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

In [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues) manual there's a mention:

> To return the keys for all matching values, use `array_keys()` with the optional `search_value` parameter instead.

So, instead of

```
$key = array_search($needle, array_column($haystack, $column));
```

use

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($haystack, $column), $needle);  // notice order of arguments
```

Comment: it works :) thanks a lot. may I ask ? is there any easy way to get these matched items ?

Comment: Isn't this way easy? Of course you can simply iterate over `$haystack` and check value of a field. But unless you have some really huge number of elements in `$haystack`, you won't notice the difference.

Comment: But if you don't need keys, but values - then follow @biziclop answer with filtering. It's more understandable.

Comment: actually, this answer is what I ask in the question but as you mentioned @biziclop answer what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_intersect and array_column.
This first finds the "register" items and matches them to the real array by keys.

```
$register = array_intersect_key($arr, array_intersect(array_column($arr, "url"), ["/register"]));
```

https://3v4l.org/pIQbZ